# EROFS when writing private directory in Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, filewriter, printwriter

I'm trying to write to my own app's private directory in Android, which should require no permissions.

It is failing.

```
val now = LocalDateTime.now()
channelDataFile = File(applicationContext.filesDir, "channel_${now.year}-${now.month}-${now.dayOfMonth}-${now.hour}-${now.minute}-${now.second}.csv")
val fileWriter = FileWriter(channelDataFile.name)
val printWriter = PrintWriter(fileWriter)
```

The fileWriter line is throwing a `android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)`.

I have tried adding a "/" in front of the filename. The applicationContext.filesDir correctly maps out to my app's data directory, "/data/user/0/com.redacted.redacted/files".

Why am I getting this exception? I just need to write files to the private directory and read them.

Comment: What is the value of channelDataFile.name?

Comment: @blackapps The value is "channel_2024-JANUARY-4-15-30-33.csv"

Comment: Well look at your code. You try to use the file writer on only that file name. You should use the whole path.